# Satzbeginn mit Kleinbuchstaben aufgrund Eigenname?

Tags: capitalization, sentence-structure

Kann ein Satz im Deutschen ausnahmsweise klein beginnen, weil ein Eigenname am Anfang steht oder muss dieser dann großgeschrieben werden oder muss dann zwingend eine neue Formulierung bzw. Satzstellung gesucht werden?

Heißt es

> [...] wurde festgelegt. **de** Maizière sagte in einem Interview [...]

oder

> [...] wurde festgelegt. **De** Maizière sagte in einem Interview [...]

oder sind beide erlaubt?

Comment: Eine Kleinschreibung am Anfang ist sehr irritierend und sieht in der Tat _falsch_ aus. In solchen Fällen schreibt man das Wort, denke ich, am besten groß, insbesondere da die Großschreibung am Anfang des Satzes die Funktion hat, seinen Beginn zu kennzeichnen. Die Frage ergibt sich auch in jeder Sprache, in der man das erste Wort eines Satzes großschreibt. Ich schätze mal, die Antwort wird überall dieselbe sein.

Comment: Auch das Französische würde den Artikel "de" am Anfang eines Satzes groß schreiben. Daher keine Gefahr, da viel falsch zu machen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Klare Sache: Der erste Buchstabe eines Satzes muss **IMMER** ein Großbuchstabe sein. Das ist eine der wenigen Regeln, die keine Ausnahme kennt.

Daher ist nur diese Version erlaubt:

> [...] wurde festgelegt. **De** Maizière sagte in einem Interview [...]

Wenn du das "de" unbedingt klein haben willst, dann stelle es ins Innere des Satzes:

> [...] wurde festgelegt. In einem Interview sagte de Maizière [...]

Comment: Im konkreten Fall ist es zwar korrekt, aber _immer_ ist nicht richtig, es gibt auch hier Ausnahmen, siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/a/61532/46548.

Answer (score 3):

Am Satzanfang muss laut Duden immer großgeschrieben werden. ([Duden/K92](https://web.archive.org/web/20150416160830/http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/gross-und-kleinschreibung#K92))

Daher ist in diesem Fall Folgendes richtig:

> [...] wurde festgelegt. **De** Maizière sagte in einem Interview [...]

Ich denke aber, dass man bei Eigennamen, die mit einem Kleinbuchstaben beginnen, auf den ein Großbuchstabe folgt, Ausnahmen machen sollte.

> iTunes verfügt über eine große Musikdatenbank. *oder:* ITunes verfügt über eine große Musikdatenbank.
>
> eBay ist das weltweit größte Internetauktionshaus. EBay ist das weltweit größte Internetauktionshaus.

Ich tendiere bei beiden Sätzen zur ersten Variante. Will man die Kleinschreibung am Satzanfang umgehen, kann man natürlich den Satz umstellen. (Siehe auch: [canoo.net](https://blog.leo.org/2008/02/27/153/))

Comment: Firmen schützen ihren Namen als Wortbildmarke. Wenn es nach ihnen geht, dann schreibt man den Namen auch nur in einem eigenen, möglichst kostenpflichtigen Font in einer ebenfallst geschützten Farbe. Der nächste wird, um aufzufallen, ein Komma in seinen Namen platzieren zusammen mit der Regel keine Leerstelle danach źu lassen. Das muss niemand mitmachen. Mich bringt auch keiner dazu Kaisers falsch zu schreiben.

Comment: Ausnahmsweise muss ich user unknown recht geben. Das was sich die Werbestrategen von Firmen in fernen Kontinenten ausdenken setzt die deutsche Rechtschreibung nicht außer Kraft. IPhones sind schöne Handys. EBay ist ein bekanntes Auktionshaus. ITunes ist eine Tochter von Apple.

Comment: Als Mathematiker werde ich eine Variable a am Satzanfag nicht groß schreiben. a sei ein Element der Menge A, ... Dem Setzer und Textverarbeitungsprogramm, dass dies verschlimmbessert sind alle meine Flüche sicher.

Comment: Ich bin bei Begriffen wie iTunes oder eBay *immer* für das Umstellen innerhalb des Satzes, weil ich sonst über das ungewohnte Wortbild stolpere. Bei Kaiser's kann man ja "Kaiser's (sic!)" schreiben.

Comment: Ich schreibe Ebay, Idings usw., mit nur dem ersten Buchstaben groß.  Bei den Idingsen sieht das zugegeben etwas albern aus, aber wenn die das Zeug so nennen kann ich ja nichts dafür.

Comment: Der Duden listet zu [iPhone](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/iPhone) und [eBay](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/eBay) auch die Schreibungen _I-Phone_ und _E-Bay_, das geht auch ohne Schmerzen am Satzanfang.

Comment: iPhone usw. werde ich am Satzanfang einfach so lassen um zu zeigen was für blöde Neuwörter das sind.

Comment: @bernd_k: Wenn das kleine a Dir so wichtig ist, dann bleibt die Möglichkeit den Satz entsprechend umzustellen. Beim a ist es auch nachvollziehbar (Verwechslung mit A) aber beim Iphone, de Maiziere usw. besteht nicht mal eine Verwechslungsgefahr, der man begegnen müsste. Bei Markennamen kann man ablesen, wie stark der Werbeaufwand das Produkt als göttlich, als tabu, als heilig und unberührbar zu inszenieren bereits verfangen hat. "Sei a ein Element der Menge A." ist übrigens längst erfunden.

Answer (score 2):

Grundsätzlich wird das erste Wort eines ganzen Satzes großgeschrieben, siehe [amtliches Regelwerk § 54](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6162#par54), und das gilt auch für Eigennamen.

Im Duden wird sogar bei der [Duden-Regel D92](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D92) ein Beispiel genannt, das deine spezielle Frage klären sollte:

> De Gaulle starb am 9. November 1970.

### Ausnahmen

Es gibt jedoch – wie fast immer – Ausnahmen (die teilweise auch auf Eigennamen anwendbar sind).

Sprachliche Regeln sind kein Selbstzweck, sondern sollen den Zweck von Sprache, also die Verständigung lediglich unterstützen. Deshalb gibt es auch im amtlichen Regelwerk einige Regeln wie [§ 45](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6159#par45) oder [§ 78](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6201#par78), bei denen Missverständnisvermeidung über die (grundsätzlichen) Regeln gestellt wird.
Auch bei der Frage nach der Großschreibung vom Satzanfang sind solche Ausnahmen denkbar und werden zum Teil auch in den Regeln selbst expliziert.

Ausnahmen laut Regeln:

- ganze Sätze innerhalb von Parenthesen: *"Sie hat das (erinnerst du dich?) gestern gesagt."* [Beispiel aus dem amtlichen Regelwerk § 54 (4)](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6162#par54-4)
- Auslassungszeichen: *"’s ist schade um sie."* [Beispiel aus dem amtlichen Regelwerk § 54 (6)](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/6162#par54-6)

Nicht explizit von den amtlichen Regeln abgedeckt sind z.B.:

- Mathematik: *"Sei a die Hypothenuse. a ist parallel zu b."*
- fachliche Bezeichnungen, die sonst missverständlich wären: *"pH-Werte unter 7 indizieren eine saure Lösung."*, *"m (für Meter) ist das Einheitenzeichen für Längenangaben."*
- Buchstaben, deren Gestalt relevant ist: *"e-förmiges Gebäck hat Ähnlichkeit zu Brezeln."*

Bei Eigennamen wie c't, dtv, eBay, iTunes hat der Linguist Dr. Bopp zwei Ratschläge:

1. Solche Namen sind *"nicht falsch oder gar „illegal“."* ([Dr. Bopp](https://blog.leo.org/2008/02/27/153/)) Das heißt, man kann "dtv" schreiben, auch am Satzanfang, und wird dann vermutlich besser verstanden, als wenn man "DTV" oder "Dtv" schreibt, auch wenn sich das vielleicht besser mit den grundsätzlichen Regeln vertragen würde.
2. *"[...] oder Sie formen den Satz so um, dass ein solcher Produktname nicht am Anfang steht"*. ([Dr. Bopp](https://blog.leo.org/2008/02/27/153/)) Das läuft also auf den bereits genannten Tipp hinaus,

> *"In einem Interview sagte de Maizière ..."*

oder

> *"Ministerpräsident de Maizière sagte in einem Interview ..."*

zu schreiben.

### Fazit

Bei "de Maizière" ist es relativ klar (nur Großschreibung ist üblich und korrekt). Bei Eigennamen im Allgemeinen ist es nicht immer so klar. Manchmal ist da eine Abweichung von der Regel aus Verständlichkeitsgründen sinnvoller – oder man umgeht das Problem durch Umformulierung.